# jQuery error - Uncaught Error: can't load XRegExp twice in the same frame

Tags: ajax, jquery, jqplot

I have a button, onclick of which I'm doing an AJAX call to one of my pages (which contains jqplot elements).

Now, the AJAX req/res works fine for the first click of the button.

When I click my button for the second time, I get an exception saying,

> Uncaught Error: can't load XRegExp twice in the same frame

And it points to the jQuery-min file. Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

I have tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424633/chrome-uncaught-error-cant-load-xregexp-twice-in-the-same-frame) and it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the handler is getting "attached" before the DOM element in question actually exists.
Try using `jquery.on()`.

Comment: using `.on()` itself.. It's getting called first time. 2nd click, I'm getting this error

Comment: Think I solved it, need to test. Will post the soln. if I did